# Is UUID supported as id type for playORM?

Tags: playorm

I am having the following exception when I try to map a class with a UUID field. The same happens with fields of kind Date. 
My entities need to have fields with these values, what could be a possible solution?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure scanning class(see chained exception)=class com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.User
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:44)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:83)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:51)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:53)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:48)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:45)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:41)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.PlayOrmConfiguration.init(PlayOrmConfiguration.java:39)
    at com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.dao.TestUserDao.testUserOperations(TestUserDao.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure scanning field=private java.util.Date com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.User.birthDate for class=User
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectField(ScannerForClass.java:179)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanFields(ScannerForClass.java:172)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanSingle(ScannerForClass.java:111)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.addClass(ScannerForClass.java:67)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:42)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for field='birthDate' in class=class com.s1mbi0se.dmp.da.bean.User.  You need to either add one of the @*ToOne annotations, @Embedded, @Transient or add your own converter calling EntityMgrFactory.setup(Map<Class, Converter>) which will then work for all fields of that type OR add @Column(customConverter=YourConverter.class) or finally if we missed a standard converter, we need to add it in file InspectorField.java in the constructor and it is trivial code(and we can copy the existing pattern)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForField.processColumn(ScannerForField.java:173)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectFieldImpl(ScannerForClass.java:205)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectField(ScannerForClass.java:177)
    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Date, we use joda-time as Date and Calendar are very buggy.  Jdk7 was supposed to integrate joda-time as it fixes all the bugs.  You can use LocalDate and LocalDateTime, etc.

For ANYTHING you can add your own converters.  When you create the NoSqlEntityManagerFactory through Bootstrap for the first time, there is a Map

```
public synchronized static NoSqlEntityManagerFactory create(DbTypeEnum type, Map<String, Object> properties, Map<Class, Converter> converters, ClassLoader cl)
```

The important map to be filled in there is

```
Map<Class, Converter> converters
```

You can supply Class=Date.class and Converter=new YourConverterForDate()

You can also supply one for UUID.  This converter map is what is used if we dont' find a converter in the standard map of converters.  In the meantime, open two issues for Date and TimeUUID and I will add those.  Also, be careful of java's TimeUUID as it is not of type X (I can't remember if X should be 1 or 4) and that makes it NOT unique :(.....there is another java library that creates unique TimeUUIDs on the web....I can look later when I have more time.

Dean

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will open two more issues and try to learn more about these converters. However, I didn't understand quite well this timeUUID thing... We are generating UUIDs by using Astyanax class UUIDSerializer, could we have a problem in this case?

Comment: Astyanax Serializer works great for serializing/deserializing UUID's but again it is the java.util.UUID in java that is type 4 UUID which is random, and if you get to trillions of rows, you will have 1 maybe 2 repeats(very hard to debug).  I prefer to use a guaranteed unique id instead so I won't have that 1 or 2 at trillions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Playorm's 1.4.1 release support UUID (com.eaio.uuid) now.

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki/Release-details